# can the ros navigation stack be used without laser scanner

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have a simple ros robot, which has odometry, an imu, and robot_pose_ekf, and I am getting almost correct trajectories in rviz. I also wrote a simple python program that gets the current heading and makes the robot move in desired direction for a given distance.

Instead of laser scanner I would like to use a top to down looking camera, and with an aruco marker on the robot, I think I will be able to determine its exact position.

Is there any way I can use the navigation stack, so I can navigate the robot into a desired goalpoint, (like within a constrained environment like a 2x2m box, with no obstacles, and the aruco system giving x,y of the robot visually)

Best Regards.
C.A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335772/can-the-ros-navigation-stack-be-used-without-laser-scanner/) by [wintermute](https://answers.ros.org/users/26115/wintermute/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2019-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming your Aruco system + odometry/ekf can give a globally accurate localization, possibly - since it is really a full replacement for AMCL at that point. Since you have no obstacle sensors, you're really just using the planners from the navigation stack. You'll need to either create a map image or write a ROS node to publish your fixed map.

One note - you'll need to make sure that your EKF/camera system gives a heading (in addition to x,y).

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2019-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2